# Quarkus + Hibernate ORM throws EnhancementException: Failed to enhance class <classname>

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

We want to use a `@MappedSuperclass` for some of our entities in a Quarkus app.

When we add a private field in the parent class we get the following exception (I replaced the field and class names with placeholders).

This issue is solved if we make the field declaration public. That's something we can live with, but I wanted to know if there is some way to keep the field private and still use the Hibernate enhancement process that Quarkus brings ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access private <fieldType> <fieldName> from class <className>
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$OffsetMapping$ForField$Resolved.resolve(Advice.java:2346)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$OffsetMapping$ForField.resolve(Advice.java:2121)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$ForMethodEnter.doApply(Advice.java:7715)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$ForMethodEnter.apply(Advice.java:7676)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$AdviceMethodInliner.visitMethod(Advice.java:7385)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1123)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:688)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Dispatcher$Inlining$Resolved$AdviceMethodInliner.apply(Advice.java:7379)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$AdviceVisitor.onAfterExceptionTable(Advice.java:9427)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.visitor.ExceptionTableSensitiveMethodVisitor.considerEndOfExceptionTable(ExceptionTableSensitiveMethodVisitor.java:49)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.visitor.ExceptionTableSensitiveMethodVisitor.visitVarInsn(ExceptionTableSensitiveMethodVisitor.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.internal.bytebuddy.InlineDirtyCheckingHandler.apply(InlineDirtyCheckingHandler.java:93)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.ByteCodeAppender$Compound.apply(ByteCodeAppender.java:151)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Appender$EmulatingMethodVisitor.resolve(Advice.java:10031)
    at net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice$Appender.apply(Advice.java:9984)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:713)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:698)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:605)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining$WithFullProcessing$RedefinitionClassVisitor.onVisitEnd(TypeWriter.java:4539)
    at net.bytebuddy.utility.visitor.MetadataAwareClassVisitor.visitEnd(MetadataAwareClassVisitor.java:271)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:692)
    at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3397)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1933)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:217)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3397)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:3614)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.make(ByteBuddyState.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.rewrite(ByteBuddyState.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.internal.bytebuddy.EnhancerImpl.enhance(EnhancerImpl.java:132)
```

Comment: Could you create a simple reproducer and attach it to a GitHub issue? That certainly looks like a bug.

Comment: Sure, I created the reproducer and the issue  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5756 . I found out that the error is only thown if the field is an @Embedded object.

Comment: Could you try to add the annotation on the getter instead of the private field?

Comment: Thanks @Davide, Adding the `@Embedded` to the getter solves the issue.

Comment: Great, I think this is a bug, though. and I've created an issue for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug and I've created an issue for it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13759

**UPDATE 2**: The bug has been solved

UPDATE 1: On further inspection, moving the annotation to the getter doesn't actually work. For now it's better to make the field public.